# Matrix Factorization with SVD/Gradient Descent - Dealing with new users

Tags: python, recommender-system, scipy

I'm working on implementing matrix factorization for a recommender system. I implemented matrix factorization, once with stochastic gradient descent and once with scipy's svds() function. The thing that I'm struggling to understand is how to incorporate a new user into the system. So one way I'm thinking of to deal with this cold-start problem is to ask the user to rate K items. But then appending this to the original dataset would require retraining for each new user which is probably not feasible.

How would I go about about predicting ratings for items for a user, given that they have been shown K items which they rated, in both of these approaches i.e. with svds() and stochastic gradient descent?